# What is a box overlay on Windows Explorer icons?

Tags: windows-explorer, icons

Using windows 11, not sure if related.
Some of my items appear with a box on the bottom left corner, and cannot be opened. For example, this is a regular PDF icon for me:

[image]

But some look like this:

[image]

[This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_shell_icon_overlay_identifiers) is the best relevant list I could find, and it doesn't mention this box. When I try to open any file with this overlay, I fail - the particular error for PDFs (via Foxit reader) is:

[image]

Comment: I do not see this (Windows 11 and Adobe).  Have you contacted Foxit Support?

Comment: @John this isn’t a pdf issue, I see similar phenomena eg for jpegs

Comment: I have had Windows 11 running since July and not seen the above behavior. I cannot duplicate it either.

Comment: What file synchronizing software do you have installed? The icon is due to some software you have installed

Comment: If I were to guess it’s probably a product from [this](https://www.box.com/overview)

Comment: Maybe OneDrive? Ill check tomorrow

Comment: Indeed, it was a OneDrive connectivity issue.   I'll leave the question here in case it helps someone some day. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When you do a websearch for you will find that these icons might appear [on files synced with OneDrive](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/what-are-these-brown-box-icons-in-left-bottom/c99d2e66-2121-4438-82eb-50584893a336):

> Are you using OneDrive? If so, that icon is for OneDrive Files on Demand.

If you look further at other search results, you'll find [this article on poremsky.com](https://www.poremsky.com/windows/brown-file-drawer-icon-windows-11/) that talks about the icons in more detail (I'm quoting some relevant bits, please visit the article to read the full explanation):

> Since upgrading to Windows 11, all of the offline Smart Sync files in Dropbox have an ugly brown icon on the lower left, instead of the light gray X I had in Windows 10.
> ...
> Microsoft updated many of the icons in Windows 11, so I checked Shell32.dll in Windows 10 to see what the icon used to look like. It showed a black clock icon in the same position in the file.
> ...
> A black clock. This means that the file has been archived to tape and will take a very long time to access.
> ...
> Although we're not archiving to tape anymore, the icon is used when the FILE_ATTRIBUTE_OFFLINE flag is set, which is why it is used for files synchronized using a cloud service. The "file" we see is a pointer to the file since the actual file is offline and it will take a little longer to open than it would if stored locally.

Bottom line: the brown box icon indicates that OneDrive syncs the file, has Files On-Demand enabled, and that this particular file is not downloaded yet. Once you double click the file OneDrive *should* download it and display it.

Now, if that doesn't work, you can try forcing OneDrive to download the file. For this right click on the file and press "Always keep on this device". Now OneDrive *should* download the file from the cloud and keep a local copy.